# ESLint space after logical NOT operator

Tags: eslint

Is there a rule in ESLint to force the use of a space after the logical operator NOT (!)?

```
!foo => KO
! foo => OK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [space-unary-ops](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/space-unary-ops) rule.

"!" is a non-word operator. You can define it for the entire category:

```
"space-unary-ops": [
    2, {
      "nonwords": true,
}]
```

Or override it specifically:

```
"space-unary-ops": [
    2, {
      "nonwords": false,
      "overrides": {
        "!": true,
      }
}]
```